# Django + Celery Remove task history after 30 days

Tags: celery, django-celery

I believe the default is the task history gets removed after 1 day. I need it to expire after 30 days.

Is `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` what I am looking for? Or do I have to make a custom cam?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=celery_task_result_expires#celery-task-result-expires

`CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` sounds like exactly what you're looking for. Make sure you check the **Note** because not all result backends are supported. Some also require celerybeat to be running.

Comment: He may also be talking about the django-celery monitor task list in the Django Admin.  In that case there's a undocumented setting for that too: https://github.com/ask/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/snapshot.py#L24-29